# Nltk tokenizer issue

Tags: python, nltk, nltokenizer

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
dataset['text'] = dataset['text'].apply(lambda word_list: [tokenizer.tokenize(word) for word in word_list])
dataset['text'].head()
```

The above code shows an error

> expected string or bytes-like object, got 'list'